# How to create regular expression to match function definitions

Tags: python, regex

I need to find function definitions like

> function (param1, param2, param3)

I am using the following regular expression in python

```
\S+\\((\S+|\s+|,)\\)
```

so that something like

```
re.findall("\S+\\((\S+|\s+|,)\\)",source_code_string)
```

should give me the all the function names, but it's not working.  Please suggest improvements to the above regular expression.  I am new to regular expressions.

Comment: "It's not working" In what way. What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: I expect it to match all the function definitions and output the function names

Comment: Do you mind if it matches other lines too? And how does it fail? Does it fail to match? Does it match too much? Give us some examples. Show some effort.

Comment: I am just looking for all the functions defined inside a source code file

Comment: Well, you can't say I didn't try.

Comment: It might also be helpful to include the language those function definitions are written in. It's obviously not Python...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is going to depend on what language the source files are written in.  Recall that in Python, function definitions are prefixed by `def` and suffixed by `:`.  Expanding on Stema's answer, try this for Python:

`^\s*def (\S+)\s*\(\s*\S+\s*(?:,\s*\S+)*\):$`

This should match only Python function definitions.  The `^` and `$` match only at the beginning and end of the line, respectively, so this will only find function defs on their own line, as they usually are for Python.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is fundamentally wrong

```
\S+\\((\S+|\s+|,)\\)
```

does mean match at least one non-whitespace, a bracket then a series of non-whitespace OR a series of whitspace OR a comma and then the closing bracket.

I think what you meant was this (use raw strings (r'') and escape only once)

```
(\S+)\s*\(\s*\S+\s*(?:,\s*\S+)*\)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2unr2)

You can then find the name of your function in the capturing group 1 (because of the brackets around the first `\S+`)

The `\s*` are optional whitespaces

**BUT** this regex is so simple, I am sure it will not find all functions (it will fail on nested brackets) and it will find other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you are looking for, but consider a few things.

- `\w+` will match any word, which can contain letters, numbers, underscores, and most other unicode word-like characters
- Using a raw string when dealing with python regex's is preferred, as you don't have to escape backslashes.  This means that you need to prefix every regex pattern with an r, like `r'this'`.  Otherwise, to match a literal backslash, you need to use `\\\\`
- When in doubt, check the [library docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), or [another source](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html) on regex's.

Comment: `\w` doesn't match a whole word, it matches a single *character* from the set of word characters.