# Regex to identify functions in expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a text which is expression formula something like

```
add(1,2)+sin(90)+1/2+add_days(now(),30)+data
```

like **add() , sin() , add_days(), now()**

Is there any way to identify functions using regular expression in javascript and replace with span tag to apply to style.

Final text needed :

```
<span> add  (</span>1,2<span>)</span>+<span>sin(</span>90<span>)</span>+1/2+<span>add_days(</span><span>now(</span><span>)</span>,30<span>)</span>+data
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (`replace`...?)

Comment: what will be my regular expression in replace ? My function will have alphabet and underscore character only@Stuart

Comment: Can we do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475577/how-to-create-regular-expression-to-match-function-definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using replace with $& solves the problem. $& helps to get matched characters in case of multiple groups.

```
var input = "add (1,2)+sin(90)+1/2+add_days(now(),30)+data";
var out = input.replace(/(?:(\s?[a-z_]+\s?\()|(\)))/ig, "<span>$&</span>");

console.log(out);

//<span>add (</span>1,2<span>)</span>+<span>sin(</span>90<span>)</span>+1/2+<span>add_days(</span><span>now(</span><span>)</span>,30<span>)</span>+data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "add (1,2)+sin(90)+1/2+add_days(now(),30)";

var output = "<span> add </span> (1,2)+<span>sin</span>(90)+1/2+<span>add_days</span>(<span>now</span>(),30)";

var out = input.replace(/(\s?[a-z_]+\s?)/ig, "<span>$1</span>");

console.log(input);
console.log(output);
console.log(out);

/*
Output:
add (1,2)+sin(90)+1/2+add_days(now(),30)
<span> add </span> (1,2)+<span>sin</span>(90)+1/2+<span>add_days</span>(<span>now</span>(),30)
<span>add </span>(1,2)+<span>sin</span>(90)+1/2+<span>add_days</span>(<span>now</span>(),30)
*/
```

Comment: It also appends if variable is added like var input = "add (1,2)+sin(90)+1/2+add_days(now(),30)+data";

Comment: data is variable should not be appended and function has brackets

Comment: Can we add brackets also to the regular expression and on replace one character ( with span closing tag

Comment: I have the same output that you expected, if you need another one, please change the original post and write a better example

Answer (score 0):

if you could list all the math functions used in your document, this could work out for you.

```
var MATH_FUNCTIONS = ['add', 'sin', 'add_days', 'now'];

var input = 'add(1,2)+sin(90)+1/2+add_days(now(),30)';

var regex = new RegExp('(\\b'+MATH_FUNCTIONS.join('\\b|')+'\\b)', 'gm');

input.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Comment: I don't know the list of function possible

Comment: @Sumeet you are going to need the list of possible functions if you are to replace them!

Comment: maybe you have another way to locate these expression formulas inside the html? like a specific css class?